# Fetching data with relationship in core data

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship

I am using core data framework and want to fetch the data using relationship. 
I have 2 entities named User and Company having user_name and company_name field's. I also have relationship to-many name rel_user->user.

Now I am trying to fetch data like this

```
User *userObj=(User*)[selectedData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSSet *resultData = [userObj valueForKeyPath:@"rel_user.user"];
    NSLog(@"subject -> %@",[resultData description]);
```

I want to show the company name related to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the name of the inverse relationship to `rel_user`? Assuming it's `rel_company` and the user -> company relation is to-one, you'd just use

```
user.rel_company.company.name
```

Where `user` is a particular `User` object.

There isn't really any benefit to specifically naming your relationships `rel`-something. It reads much nicer to have a `company` relationship on the User (since it will be a property holding the Company) and a `users` relationship on the Company. You can then tell from the name what the property will contain and if it is a to-one or to-many relationship.

Comment: Hello Thank you for replying but I can't find the relationship property with the User object. How can I get that do I need to set parent class for that??

Comment: You define the relationships yourself in the core data model editor. If you don't create subclasses, you'll have to use valueForKeyPath.

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch related company name by relation name.

User *userObj=(User*)[selectedData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *companyName = userObj.RELATION_NAME.company_name

RELATION_NAME is used to connect from user entity to company entity.

Hope this will help.